# A Blu-Ray drive to add to the MacBook 7,1?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am working on downgrading my laptop to make some extra money while having a beefy Windows PC for gaming, VR and other things...and I just really need a laptop for the go, and decided that the MacBook 7,1 was most appealing to me.

Since I can upgrade it with RAM, SATA drives and even it's ODD, I wondered if there was a way to plop a Blu-Ray drive into this? I would like to watch some DH Blu-Rays sometimes. Most of my anime collection is physical, therefore I need a physical drive to play them back.

What drive can I get to do an upgrade?

Comment: Be warned that model of computer is no longer supported in the newest OS versions.

Comment: Officially no. Inofficially, yes ;) I am aware of that. I received the unit today and am actually dropping Catalina onto it right now. Thanks for your info tho!

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here:

[Which internal Blu-ray drives are compatible with a unibody Macbook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/which-internal-blu-ray-drives-are-compatible-with-a-unibody-macbook-pro?rq=1)

Be aware that the OS itself won't play back BluRay movies; Steve Jobs was on the record as saying that BluRay's DRM were "a bag of hurt". The linked question has among its answers a link to a supposed workaround for this, but that link no longer works.

Comment: Thank you! Still figuring out if this also applies to that white plastic-y (forgot the actual term - not a native speaker) MacBook. But this sure does look promising! Thank you very much :)